# how to compare two table in same database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I new to MYSQL query. I have two different tables in same database. Each tables are 3 column only. I want compare to second table from first table.

table 1:

```
path -> C:/sume/sorve/data001/data001.jpg
frn -> 256423
byte -> 153

table 2:
path -> C:/ones/elsa/data001/data001.jpg
frn -> 256423
byte -> 153
```

I need match (data001/data001.jpg, 256423, 153), How can I do this? because some data001 sub directory before always come different directory.

what records not match with second table, I need that records..

Comment: are there column name path,frn,byte ?

Comment: yes, two tables are same column name and column count also same,

Comment: Is the path path `C:/sume/sorve` that should be disregarded the same in all rows in Table1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one

```
    select t1.* from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on 
        substring_index(t2.path, '/', -1) =  substring_index(t1.path, '/', -1) 
        and t2.frn = t1.frn 
        and t2.byte = t1.byte
    where t2.path is null or t2.frn is null or t2.byte is null
```

**Edited for path. Now check it should work**

Comment: C:/sume/sorve/ Note this location with second table data001/data001.jpg only match before all directory are different, so I can't match direcly with path.

Answer (score 0):

If the paths are static (ie the same for all entries in each table), you can just replace that part with an empty string as a part of a normal `LEFT JOIN`;

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
  ON REPLACE(t1.`path`, 'C:/sume/sorve/', '') = 
     REPLACE(t2.`path`, 'C:/ones/elsa/', '') 
 AND t1.`frn`  = t2.`frn`
 AND t1.`byte` = t2.`byte`
WHERE t2.`path` IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e0af6/1).

Note that this search will *not do well with indexes*, and is nothing you should do as a matter of rendering a web page. If it's something you need to do often, you may want to make the path in the database relative and only add the absolute path part when needed to access the file.